# How to translate 因為所以科學道理?

Tags: translation, idioms

I heard this from native speakers but am confused about its meaning. I understand every word but this phrase itself does not make much sense to me.

Comment: It does not make much sense to me (a native) either.

Comment: I've heard this used many times, often jokingly. I think you could treat it asa fixed expression, although i have no idea how common it is. It's certainly not something someone made up on the spur of the moment, though.

Comment: if the context is clear, you can reduce long sentences by stating only the keywords and people would still understand

Answer (score 6):

I remember the the full slang was like
因为所以
科学道理
国家机密
干嘛告你
which was used when this person does not want to explain something, so he/she explains it with nonsense instead.
But it was a really old slang we used in primary school in 2000s.

Comment: Yeah, I think that was it. I just recalled it. It's joking. It's a 顺口溜.

Answer (score 3):

This native speaker certainly reduced a sentence to a list of single terms. Let me expand it back to a regular sentence

- 因為所以科學道理  (because therefore scientific truth)
- 因為， 所以， 科學道理.  (Because, Therefore, Scientific truth)
- 有 '因為' 之後就有 '所以'. 這是一個科學的道理 (When there is a 'because' we'll have a 'therefore'. It is a scientific truth

Another way to interpret this sentence: '有原因就有結果' 是一個符合科學的道理 ('A cause will be followed by an effect' is a scientific truth)

People don't usually talk like this, maybe the speaker was annoyed, so he reduced a sentence into a single terms list, to express a sentiment of 'I don't want to waste my breath to explain this simple truth to you'

Something similar: 'Guns (bring) Death', (It is this) simple! --> “槍械 (帶來) 死亡”，(就是這麼) 簡單！--> Guns, Death, Simple! --> 槍械，死亡，簡單！

Answer (score 3):

**Because.**

You know that snarky little one word answer that kids like to give? That's 因为所以(科学道理).

---

Although, and this is quite bizarre, *Cambridge* gives almost the exact same English example in its dictionary when explaining the word [because](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/because):

> used before giving a short reason or explanation, especially when you think the reason or explanation is obvious or you do not want to explain more:
> "Why does that happen?" "Because science."

Answer (score 0):

I think the translation will be this.

**Because it is scientific?**

I think you can use this phrase when somebody insists on self-assertion.

Answer (score 0):

If little kids refuse to answer the question "why", they will naughtily reply with the following nonsensical rhyme:

> 因为所以，科学道理，
>
> 化学物理，声学地理。
>
> 美国总统，没钱买米。
>
> 你妈打你，我不帮你。

which literally means

> Because therefore, scientific reason,
>
> chemistry physics, acoustics geography.
>
> POTUS has no money to buy rice.
>
> You mom hit you and I won't help you.

(Note: Don't ask why the grammar is too poor to understand. The original Chinese text is pure nonsense. The original Chinese text is in wrong grammar.)

How can I translate it into English?

> No reason.

or

> Just because.